# Rectangle with rounded corners, but defined stroke on each side

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using this for my listview background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#C98E04"/>
<stroke android:width="0.25dp"
        />

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         /> 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

The problem is that between each listview item, the border is thicker then the frame.
How can I define a thiner top border (stroke) ?

Answer (score -1):

you can minimize size of stroke to 0.1 and in listview add this to minimize the didvei gap android:dividerHeight="2dp"